# Get last two digits SQL

Tags: sql, function, informix, digits

I Need to find a solution to get the last two digits of a value in the column. Im using informix sql and the values in the column are always only numbers but in various lenghts.
Thanks for any advice!

I dont know how to start or if there is any function that will make it easier

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: The data type is a char

Comment: Why not start by looking at the available string functions and trying something?

Comment: Informix converts strings to numbers readily.  I'd take advantage of that with `MOD(column, 100)`.  You will get errors if any of the strings cannot be converted to a number.  It will handle single-digit numbers with aplomb.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RTRIM` to trim trailing spaces. Use `CHAR_LENGTH` to get the number of digits, and calculate the start position. Use `SUBSTRING` to get the last two digits.

```
SUBSTRING(column FROM CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(column)) - 1 FOR 2)
```

Or, use `REVERSE` twice:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(RTRIM(column)) FROM 1 FOR 2))
```